# Akka stream vs Hive Stream

Tags: apache-spark, hive, akka, apache-nifi, akka-stream

I am working on a requirement where we need to read messages from Kafka and save (sink) to Hive. I can think about of multiple implementation using different technologies:

1. Akka stream - where source will be Kafka source and sink to hive
2. Hive Stream - using hive streaming
3. Spark streaming
4. nifi - https://nifi.apache.org/

What would be best way to handle large set of kafka messages to stream with Hive?

Thanks 
Arun

Comment: Apache spark would be better for process large amount of data in batch mode.

Comment: thanks I would like to know the elaborated difference why not nifi or akka stream or hive stream ... I would use apache spark only in case of I have to perform some computation on large data, this process is more like read and save (sink), zero computation (like sum, avg, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Best is of course a very vague concept, but I personally like NiFi as a data movement solution.

If you are looking for fast development, and clear monitoring then the intuitive GUI should prove very valuable.

If you find that you cannot get enough performance, or good enough latency, you might be able to improve with Spark Streaming, but often that should not be needed.

Ful disclosure: Have not worked with Akka Streams, and work for Cloudera a driving force behind Nifi, Spark and Hive